# Running ubuntu from a usb stick, cant install anything

Tags: boot, usb, software-installation, software-center

i am currently running ubuntu from a usb stick because my hard drive is corrupt. I am trying to install Crossover from Ubuntu Software and when i click "install" it starts for a split second then ends as if i never clicked install. I tried installing it through terminal and it just gives me the held  broken packages error. I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Generally installing anything from a Live USB won't work as well as a proper install since you are installing everything within memory unless you have created a persistence file on the USB device as well...  In terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

...and then use synaptic package manager to enable and reload repositories and then try installing crossover again if there's enough memory...  Failing that install Ubuntu onto your borked HD and try from there.